# SQL Select distinct column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a MySQL table that has the following entries;

```
ID,     PRODUCTID
95,     2
95,     2
95,     1
96,     1
102,    1
102,    5
95,     5
```

How do I select the PRODUCTID(s) that only have one distinct ID-column value.

The result I want to get back is:

```
PRODUCTID
2
```

I have tried something in the lines of;

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTID
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP  BY ID, PRODUCTID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `productid` and then use a `count(distinct id)` to count unique `id`s

```
SELECT PRODUCTID
FROM your_table
GROUP BY PRODUCTID
HAVING COUNT(distinct ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.PRODUCTID 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.PRODUCTID = x.PRODUCTID 
            AND y.ID <> x.ID 
          WHERE y.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` is one way to solve this problem.  However, I prefer to compare `MIN()` and `MAX()` -- because these are cheaper to calculate:

```
SELECT PRODUCTID
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY PRODUCTID
HAVING MIN(ID) = MAX(ID);
```

If `ID` could be `NULL`, you would need to add another condition:

```
SELECT PRODUCTID
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY PRODUCTID
HAVING (MIN(ID) = MAX(ID) AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(ID)) OR  -- No NULL values
        (MIN(ID) IS NULL);                              -- or all NULL values
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ID,     PRODUCTID
95,     2
95,     2
95,     1
96,     1
102,    1
102,    5
95,     5
you can use this this is working fine
SELECT distinct product_id from  category GROUP  BY id, product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```